# view.addSubview(: ) Not working in swift playgrounds

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I've got a swift playground and I've created a UIButton called 'startButton'.

I have a function that sets up the parameters of the UIButton.

```
    func setupStartButton() {
        startButton.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 550, width: 125, height: 50)
        startButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(ciColor: CIColor(red: 255/255, green: 0/255, blue: 77/255, alpha: 1.0))
        startButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        startButton.setTitle("Start", for: .normal)
        startButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        startButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(startButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(startButton)
    }
```

I call this in the viewDidLoad

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 524, height: 766))
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        setupStartButton()

        PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
        PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
    }
```

When I run the playground it doesn't show the button.
How do I show the button.
Thank you

Comment: Basically a playground is not a good place for this. Use a real app project.

Comment: I'm building a project for WWDC scholarship program, which sadly has to be in playgrounds.

Comment: btw, there is no need to create a `CIColor` just to create a `UIColor` from it. You can create `UIColor` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `PlaygroundPage.current.liveView` to the local `view` created in `viewDidLoad`. This is not the same view of the view controller which is what you are adding the button to in the `setupStartButton`.

I would remove the line `let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 524, height: 766))` then every reference to `view` will be the view controller's view.

You should remove the playground code from the `viewDidLoad` method. After the view controller class, you can create an instance of the view controller and setup the playground:

Something like:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    // your code
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```